# Sqlite-No such table error

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created my database with **Sqlite database browser** and put it in my **assets** folder, but when i use the **call()** method it gives me the error:
 **No Such Table DailyWorks**

here is the **on create** code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    CopyDatabaseintheEmulatorMemory();  // Copy database in memory of emulator
     call();

}

private void call() 
{
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

     //---get all contacts---
    db.open();

    String sql="select * from DailyWorks";

    Cursor c = db.getAllContacts(sql);

    db.close();     
}
```

And the DBAdapter class is:

```
public class DBAdapter {

    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;


    final Context context;

    DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static  class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
        }

     }

    //---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---
    public void close() 
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }
    //---retrieves all the contacts---
    public Cursor getAllContacts(String sql)
    {
        return db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what does `CopyDatabaseintheEmulatorMemory` do?

Comment: It check the emulator and if there is not any database there it will copy database from _assets_ to emulator memory. To make the code shorter i have omitted it but if it is necessary i will add them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before accessing your database from assets folder you have to copy your database to your device's package memory. because your application will access databse from your package only.
sample code:

```
String DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/";   
String DB_NAME = "database";
 InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
      String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
      OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      int length;
      while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
       myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
      }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this i do this in _CopyDatabaseintheEmulatorMemory_

Comment: If i do this whenever i make a new object of the databasehelper it will copy it and i may lose some of the records which i  insert into the database.

Comment: Ok you were right, just a few changes in my CopyDatabaseintheEmulatorMemory  makes it correct
Thanks